# Asynctask and parsing JSONObject from url NullPointerException

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, html-parsing

Here's my problem.

I've tried to get a `JSONObject` from an `url`. Here's my parser :

```
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";
    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {
    }
    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

Here's my main activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private TextView tv;
    private static final String urllisteemplois = "the url that contains the json";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        JParse jParse = new JParse(urllisteemplois);
        jParse.execute();
        String result = jParse.concat();
        tv.setText(result);
    }
}
```

And here's my ASynctask :

```
public class JParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
    private String url;
    private JSONObject json;

    public JParse(String url) {
        this.url=url;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json2 = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        return json2;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json2) {
        this.json=json2;
    }

    public String concat()
    {
        String result = this.json.toString()+"hello";
        return result;
    }
}
```

I get this error :

```
01-20 03:18:43.797    2298-2298/com.aziz.bdk.ryadencule E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.aziz.bdk.ryadencule, PID: 2298
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aziz.bdk.ryadencule/com.aziz.bdk.ryadencule.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference
```

I tried some stuff and I know that in the `onPostExecute`, `this.json` is not `null` and contains my parsed `JSON`, in the `concat()` method it is `null`.

Also, I need to add `onPostExecute(json2)` in `doInBackground(..)`, it won't do it automatically.

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1):

This code in `onCreate` is the problem:

```
jParse.execute();
String result = jParse.concat();
tv.setText(result);
```

since the `AsyncTask` is asynchronous the call to jParse.execute() is still running when you call jParse.concat() and the json object is still null.

You should do only the first line in `onCreate` and then move the second two lines to `onPostExecute` in your JParse object.

Comment: Thank you for you answer.

I actually created an interface with only one method that I called at the very end of onPostExecute, and that i overrode in my MainActivity to use to concat method.

Comment: `onPostExecute` is basically a "callback" to the UI thread, just so you know. In other words, it's kind of like you created an interface for an interface. It's designed to allow calls on the UI thread so that you don't have to create thread-safe callback like you did. However, what you did is useful if you're using standard threads...